# Angularjs: How to pass data to a custom Service from a Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am currently working on a project that involves getting data from a server. The data is passed to the main controller through a custom service that uses a custom directive which gets data from the server. Below you can find the code:

```
/* Service requestObjects */
app.factory('requestObjects', ['customDirective', function(customDirective){ 
  return {
    getObjects: function (){
      return customDirective.call('address', {
        // parameters for the call
        pageIndex: 1,
        pageSize: 20
      }).then(function (list) {
        return list;
      })
    }
  }
}])

/* Controller */

app.controller ('MainController', ['$scope', 'requestObjects', function($scope, requestObjects){
  requestObjects.getObjects().then(function (data){
    $scope.objectList = data;
    $scope.$apply();
  })
  $scope.addPage = function(){
    $scope.objectList.currentPageIndex += 1;
  }
}])
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="addPage()">Load more objects</button>
```

The HTML file has a button which increased the currentPageIndex with 1 when clicked however no other objects are loaded on the page. 
Is there anyway to tell the service that I want the next page with the next 20 objects and load them, when the button is clicked, on the page?

Comment: You do not have a custom directive, you have a factory, which is a singleton service.

Comment: I understand. So what needs to be changed for me to make this work? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a setter function to your service:

```
setObjects: function(...) { ... }
```

Then call `requestObject.setObjects(...)` in your controller to pass your data in. How you save and what you do with the data passed in will be determined by your implementation of `setObjects` in the service.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for the idea. I am looking also for a way to implement this into the service that I built. Do you have an example on how this might work?

Comment: You could use `setObjects` to change the data in your directive directly rather than storing the data within the service. I don't know much about your directive or the rest of your code so I can't help much with implementation. Alternatively, if you want to store your data in your service, you could add a variable within your service to do so. Then your `getObjects` would change to simply return that variable, `setObjects` would change that variable, and you would add another function to update the variable from the data in your directive.